# Aligning images using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, homography

I have a collection of roughly 250 images. All of them were scanned from a book, hence they are all shifted or rotated a little with regards to each other. Now I would like to do some data extraction on these images, but in order to do this automatically all the positions in all the images should be identical. That's why I need to somehow align these images so that all position in all images correspond with each other. What would be the best way to achieve this? I figured openCV is the best method to do this, but I'm not sure how I should start.

Below is an example of a scanned image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dotted lines are probably a good anchor point.

- Turn the dotted lines into solid lines using a [Morphological Transformation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#morphological-transformations).
- Identify lines using [HoughLines](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html#hough-line-transform)
- Draw the lines on a mask

You can use the mask to align separate images. Scan the edges of the masks for the coordinates and use those to rotate and shift the images. With that I mean looping through the values of the top row of the mask. The first white pixel gives the top center coordinate. Similar for the other sides of the mask. You can compare these values over different images to determine shift and rotation. To apply those transformations read [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html#geometric-transformations-of-images). This will take quite some work though. Perhaps there is an easier option:

I may be wrong, but it seems you want to align the pages, so you can extract the graphs using hardcoded values. A different, easier, approach would be to use [findContours](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#contours-getting-started) to create subimages of the 'tiles'. These can then be further processed. This is implemented in the code below.

[image]

Separated subimages:

[image]

Code:

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np  
    # load image
    img_large=cv2.imread("BAgla.jpg")
    # resize for ease of use
    img_ori = cv2.resize(img_large, None, fx=0.2, fy=0.2, interpolation= cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    # create grayscale
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img_ori, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # create mask for image size
    mask = np.zeros((img.shape[:2]),dtype=np.uint8)
    # do a morphologic close to merge dotted line
    kernel = np.ones((8,8))
    res = cv2.morphologyEx(img,cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    # detect edges for houglines
    edges = cv2.Canny(res, 50,50)
    # detect lines
    lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
    # draw detected lines
    for line in lines:
            rho,theta = line[0]
            a = np.cos(theta)
            b = np.sin(theta)
            x0 = a*rho
            y0 = b*rho
            x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
            y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
            x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
            y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

            cv2.line(mask,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255),2)
            cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(127),2)

    # invert the mask for use with findcontours
    mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
    # use findcontours to get the boundingboxes of the tiles
    contours, hier = cv2.findContours(mask_inv,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    boundingrects = []
    for cnt in contours:
            boundingrects.append(cv2.boundingRect(cnt))

    # findContours has no garanteed order, so sort array
    boundingrects.sort()

    # titles for window names / save file names
    title = ['Kaart', None, 'Smaakprofiel', 'Basiswaarden','Gelijkaardige bieren','Chemisch Profiel']

    # create images for top and bottom tiles
    for index in [0,2,3,5]:
            x,y,w,h = boundingrects[index]
            subimg = img_ori[y:y+h,x:x+w]
            cv2.imshow(title[index], subimg  )

    # combine middle tiles
    x1,y1,w1,h1 = boundingrects[1]
    x2,y2,w2,h2 = boundingrects[4]
    subimg = img_ori[y1:y2+h2,x1:x2+w2]
    cv2.imshow(title[4], subimg  )

    # display result
    cv2.imshow("Result", img  )
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask  )
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note that I used a downsized version of the image, so account for that when processing the images.

Comment: Okay, so far I understand how to transform and detect the lines. But then you said it is possible to "use the mask to align separate images". How would I go about doing this? You stated that I could scan the edges of the masks for the coordinates and use those to rotate and shift the images. Honestly I would have no idea how to do this... Should I apply the positions of these lines from the first image to all other 250 images? Or what would be the best approach?

Comment: I tend to get an error on the following line `ret, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(mask_inv,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`. It says `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`

Comment: That is because you have a newer version of openCV. Simply remove the `ret,` as that value is no longer returned: `contours, hier = cv2.findContours(mask_inv,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`. I also updated the answer

Comment: Alright thanks, then one more question. You are downsizing the image for ease of use. Does this have any implications if I want to extract data from the graphs in the subimages? If so, what should I account for when using the full-size images?

Comment: The easiest approach is to modify how the subimage is created. Instead of `img_ori`, use `img_large` and multiply the subimage dimension with 5 (because the image was downsized to 20%). Unpretty: `subimg = img_large[y*5:y*5+h*5,x*5:x*5+w*5]`

Comment: Or is it possible to use img_large right from the start instead of downsizing it?

Comment: Of course. You will have to tweak `morphologyEx` to make the dotted line properly connect into a solid line. Maybe the `Canny` and `HoughLines` too. Just try a few things and see the effect. The overall result will be the same though, except processing a downsized image is more efficient. So I would advice the multiplication method.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. I noticed that you sort the array of boundingrects, however this does not seem to make a uniform ordering of all the subimages. The thing is that I would only like to use the subimages containing the circular graphs, but in order to extract these from the boundingrects array, the ordering should be consistent. In most cases I figured that index 2 and 5 seem correct, but there are some images that produce different orderings. Any idea how this is possible and how this can be fixed?

Comment: I noticed that on some of the scanned images, the line where the next page of the book starts is visible on the scan. This line does seem to interfere with the detection of the contours to create subimages. Can I somehow ignore this line while not ignoring the dotted lines that are necessary? 
Edit: After some cropping I noticed that the line was not the only problem, somehow the horizontal dotted lines get detected twice, while the vertical lines don't get detected. Could this have something to do with slight rotation of the scans?

Comment: After a while trying to figure it out, I've come to the conclusion that the HoughLines transformation detects multiple lines from the Canny edge detection. So somehow, I should try to "smooth" the output of canny so that hough only detects single lines instead of multiple ones... However, I've been trying to fix that for a while now, I have no idea how.

Comment: The sort is based on the x / y values. If the page is tilted, this can throw of a consistent sort. You can instead determine the right one using a decision tree. Something like if x < 25% of page width and y > 50% of page length, then it's the bottom left.

Comment: As to the line detection, that gets to involved to handle in the comments. Best to open a new question. Edit: just saw you already have.

Comment: Yup, I created a new question. The wrong subimage ordering was due to wrong subimages being created because of bad line detection.